# Inkscape converted file not recognize

Tags: inkscape, svg, google

I have saved an SVG file to WMF and EMF file format using Inkscape (0.91). However Google Drawing do not recognize these files. However when I use online tool for conversion (CloudConvert) Google Drawing can open WMF and EMF files.

Is there anything special about Inkscape conversion? What other tool (in Linux but not online) I can use to convert SVG file to WMF and EMF?

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, cNinja. Your question is not clear, can you add some details about the exported file?

Comment: Four years later this question is still relevant. The EMF files that Inkscape generates are incompatible with Google Drawing. The only EMF files that Google recognises are those produced by CloudConvert.

Answer (score 0):

The manual says that, if you used a feature for making text flow inside a shape, then other SVG engines might refuse to load your file. 
This is a feature that was proposed for the standard but finally didn't make it.

Comment: True, but Google Drawing import fails even with simple SVG shapes